# Golang net/http package Post call returns base64

Tags: xml, go

Somehow below call returns base64 string instead of xml output. I need to decode this to see xml.

```
// POST 
func (u *UserResource) authenticateUser(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
    Api := new(Api)
    Api.url = "http://api.com"
    usr := new(User)
    err := request.ReadEntity(usr)
    if err != nil {
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    buf := []byte("<api version=\"6.0\"><request>test</request></api>")

    r, err := http.Post(Api.url, "text/plain", bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
    if err != nil {
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "plain/text")
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    response.WriteEntity(body)
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and have correct xml output?

Comment: `http.POST` does not send base 64, unless explicitly asked. What it returns, is probably up to the server, it contacts.

Comment: Please edit your question without the fluff around it. I assume you are only interested in the POST request, right? You should give us a chance to try your code.

Comment: Are you creating a proxy server?

Comment: @RickyA Yes it is used as a Proxy

Comment: @DewyBroto I'm usinig Go-Restful package. https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful

Comment: Excellent! Please put this as Answer! Thx

Comment: @DewyBroto how do I change to XML or JSON the r.Body part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses the Go-Restful [WriteEntity](http://godoc.org/github.com/emicklei/go-restful#Response.WriteEntity) method to write a []byte containing XML to the response body. The WriteEntity method marshals the value to XML or JSON using the standard encoding packages. These packages marshal []byte values as base64 strings.

Changing the last line above to

```
response.Write(body)
```

will write the remote server's response to the client without JSON or XML encoding.

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I decode this so it show XML?

Comment: Go restful has got Swagger UI integration hence why I'm using it unless Swagger is easy to implement with Golang?